# How to close bootstrap accordion one at a time

Tags: angularjs

I just want to open all `accordions` for the first time. After that if I click on any of the accordion it closes all others. I want to close one at a time.
Please see plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BSTqkGCCYyZt4KZjgeuo?p=preview).Fix my code if anything is wrong in that.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/BSTqkGCCYyZt4KZjgeuo?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you click on any accordion you are toggling `status.isFirstOpen`
try this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1tBUyu8ZAsUHakJVWE0z?p=preview) instead. Just watch for events on `isOpen` of your first accordion group

```
  $scope.$watch('groups[0].isOpen', function(isOpen) {
      for (i = 0; i < $scope.groups.length; i++ ) {
        $scope.groups[i].isOpen = isOpen;
      }
  });
```

Edit: If all you want is for the accordions to be open initially, create the group items with `isOpen: true`. No need for the event watching above.

```
$scope.items.push({name:'Item ' + newItemNo, isOpen: true});
```

Comment: Actually, Your solutions was correct for My question.So Accepting you Answer.  But, I want all accordions to be open for the first time without any click event on any accordion(meaning first time when page loads). After that it should open or close depending on accordion clicked.

Comment: Thanks lyjackal. Actually  i get group items from server. I don't want to modify items and add one more attribute as isOpen. If there is any better solution than this then I will try. However, for now your old solutions is good enough.